# Get Tweets from a business page

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I have to get feeds from a business page (like https://twitter.com/insead). It is not for a specific user. How can I use twitter api to fetch this . I would appreciate if someone can give some input in context of LINQ-to-Twitter C# api for this purpose as well.

Regards
Raghav

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use their twitter widgets.

[image]

You could also customize twitter widgets' height, theme and link color.

Comment: Thanks but I need to  customize the style of how it shows and secondly need only the top feed to be shown.